# HttpStatus and DownloadData

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to download a file (an image) with RestSharp using the DownloadData method

```
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

var request = new RestRequest("GetImage", Method.GET);

var response = client.DownloadData(request);
```

This works fine, but if the requests returns an error I cannot see the HttpStatus code.

I could make a Request and check the status:

```
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

var request = new RestRequest("GetImage", Method.GET);

var response = client.Execute(request);

var status = response.StatusCode;
```

But then I cannot get the image from the Content property.

I'm I missing something obvious?

Comment: i don't know the odds of browsing SO at 1am and seeing a restsharp question at the top of the list, but i'm guessing they're low :)

Comment: Here in Denmark it's 10AM, but I'm happy that you are on SO that late :-)

Comment: _"But then I cannot get the image from the Content property."_ Because `DownloadData()` returns a byte array, and `Execute()` returns a RestResponse (which has the data in its RawBytes property). [Read the source, Luke](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.Sync.cs).

Comment: Somehow I missed the RawBytes property - my bad.

Comment: A little late, but is there way to get progress updates on a file download?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The image data would be in `RestResponse.RawBytes`

Comment: Since that is exactly what [DownloadData()](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.Sync.cs) returns. :)

Comment: Excelent! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: Great! Feel free to click the check over on the left and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Done, apperently you can only mark as answer after 10 minutes, and thanks.