# C# - File getting corrupted while Downloading from DropBox

Tags: c#, rest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a requirement where I need to download a file from dropbox.

The following is the code snippet to accomplish this task

```
try{
        string path="sundar.jpg";
        var restClient = new RestClient("http://api-content.dropbox.com/1/");
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("files/auto/Public/sundar.jpg", Method.GET);                       
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer FAAAAAAwqefsdLacFIAAAAAAAAPX2dcjMu04hScVxu7gdWJPUi");                       
        Byte[] responseData = restClient.DownloadData(request);
        Console.WriteLine(responseData);
        ByteArrayToFile("C:\\Tim\\newuns.jpg", responseData);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

What I get is an jpg file downloaded but the issue is that jpg file is corrupted. I believe I need to tweak this code a bit. Any pointer on how to accomplish this would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Below is the code of ByteArrayToFile

```
 public static bool ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray)
{
   try
   {
    System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = 
     new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                              System.IO.FileAccess.Write);     
  _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length);    
  _FileStream.Close();    
  return true;
   }
   catch (Exception _Exception)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}",
                    _Exception.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: First, post *all the relevant code*. What does `ByteArrayToFile` do? If you have a file error, you should first check the method that deals with files. Second, does the request work or does it return an error status code? Check this [possibly duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346901/httpstatus-and-downloaddata) - use Execute to get a response and check its HttpStatus

Comment: Updated the question with ByteArrayToFile function.

Comment: Does the request work though, or does it return an error code? You may be getting a 400 (Bad Request) or 401 (Unauthorized), 404 (Missing) code instead of data

Comment: Use `File.WriteAllBytes` instead of rolling your own. Have you looked at the contents of that file? How do you know it is corrupt?

Comment: Thanks every soul who helped me. @ Panagiotis - Heartful thanks to you. The issue is API call shoudl not be made as a HTTP instead as HTTPS. That resolved the issue